# modern treatment of the triviality of the multiplicator of the finite special linear group

Tags: representation-theory, group-cohomology

Given your favorite version of the Heisenberg group one can prove the Stone-Von Neumann theorem. It is then not to hard to construct a family of representations on a central
extension of $Sp\left(2n, F\right)$ by $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, where for me $F$ is a local field.

In a past project I constructed such a representation in the case when $n=1$ and $F$ is finite, and I would like to deduce this special construction from the general construction outlined in my first paragraph. I believe this reduces to showing that when $F$ is 
finite $H^2 \left( SL_2 \left(F\right) , \mathbb{C}^{\times} \right)$ is trivial when $F$ has odd order not equal to 9.

That said, I've been bouncing back and forth between books and google trying to find a proof of the triviality of this Schur multiplier.Indeed I found one in Schur's 1904 paper

"Uber die Darstellung der endlichen Gruppen durch gebrochene lineare Substitutionen."

However I was hoping that in the more than 100 years since Schur published this there has been a less German and more modern treatment of the triviality of $H^2 \left(SL_2 \left(F\right), \mathbb{C}^{\times} \right)$. So I'm wondering, is there such a treatment? Perhaps, as an alternative to a reference, someone could provide a sketch of the proof.

Edit 1: In the Atlas of Groups one can find an algorithm to calculate the Schur multiplier
of a finite group, given generators and relations. However, I'd hope that there is a less computational proof that better capitalizes on the specific nature of the group $SL_2 \left(F\right)$.

Edit 2:Geoff Robinson and Jack Schmidt have pointed out that the Schur multiplier is nontrivial in the case that $F$ has order 4 or 9. Hopefully, my revised question is answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is just a partial answer to indicate that one mostly knows the multiplier from basic group theory.

If *G* = SL( 2, *q* ) for some prime power *q* = *p*<sup>*k*</sup>, then the Sylow *r*-subgroups of *G* are either:

- Quaternion if *r* = 2 ≠ *p*,
- Cyclic if 2 ≠*r* ≠ *p*,
- Elementary abelian if *r* = *p*

In the first two cases, the Sylow *r*-subgroup already has trivial multiplier, so *G* has trivial *r*-multiplier, as in pages 107–108 and 117 of Schur (1907) or page 170 of Aschbacher's Finite Group Theory and pages 123, 151, 153 of Isaacs's Finite Group Theory.

> In particular, the multiplier of *G* is always a *p*-group.

One can even calculate the multiplier of a nicer group, *B*, where the relations are easier to understand.

---

Caveat: I haven't finished the calculation, but perhaps here is one way to approach it.

Since the Sylow *p*-subgroup *P* is abelian, *B* = N<sub>*G*</sub>(*P*) controls the multiplier, that is, the multiplier of *G* is isomorphic to the multiplier of *B*.  I think one could simply calculate the multiplier (start with the multiplier of *P* and the take into account the GF(*q*)<sup>×</sup> = *B* / *P* action, where it acts as squares; this is done on page 118–119 of Schur (1907)).  Large *k* should have trivial multiplier because of the large action of GF(*q*)<sup>×</sup>, and small *k* should be trivial since the multiplier of *P* is already small.  Apparently something goes wrong for medium sized *k*, at least when *q* = 4 or *q* = 9.

When *q* = 4, one gets *B* ≅ AGL(1,4) ≅ A<sub>4</sub> which has SL(2,3) as a double cover.  When *q* = 9, one actually gets an action of GF(*q*)<sup>×</sup> on an extra-special 3-group as a triple cover of *B*.

In general you would have to get:

$$ \hat B = \langle a, b_i, z_{ij} : a^{q-1} = b_i^p = z_{ij}^p = 1, b^a = b^{(\zeta^2)}, [b_i,b_j]= z_{ij}, z_{ij} \in Z(\hat B) \rangle$$

and I guess the question is how *a* can act consistently on both *b* and *z* without forcing *z* = 1.  This appears to be a matrix congruence over GF(*q*), and so is probably equivalent to Schur's method.  Presumably it is also understandable as looking at alternating forms on GF(*q*)<sup>2</sup>, so related to your original Sp(2, *F*) problem.

---

At any rate here is a bibliography with some links.

- Schur, J.
  Über die Darstellung der endlichen Gruppen durch gebrochene lineare Substitutionen.
  J. für Math. 127, 20-50 (1904).
  JFM[35.0155.01](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:35.0155.01)
  URL:[GDZPPN002165511](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/resolveppn/GDZPPN002165511)
- Schur, J.
  Untersuchungen über die Darstellung der endlichen Gruppen durch gebrochene lineare Substitutionen.
  J. für Math. 132, 85-137 (1907).
  JFM[38.0174.02](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:38.0174.02)
  URL:[GDZPPN00216633X](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/resolveppn/GDZPPN00216633X)
- Aschbacher, Michael.
  *Finite group theory.*
  Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 10.
  Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1986. x+274 pp.
  ISBN: 0-521-30341-9
  MR[895134](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=895134)
  Google [books](http://books.google.com/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA170)
- Isaacs, I. Martin
  *Finite group theory.*
  Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 92.
  American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2008. xii+350 pp. 
  MR[2426855](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2426855)
  Google books:
  ** [p. 118](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA118) lemma,
  ** [p. 123](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA123) quaternions have no multiplier,
  ** [p. 151](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA151) def. of multiplier,
  ** [p. 153](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA153) triviality of more multipliers.

Comment: There are actually only 6 exceptions to when $SL(n,q)$ doesn't have trivial Schur multiplier.  The hardest to compute (by hand, anyway) is probably $SL(3,4)$. In Steinberg's *Lectures on Chevalley Groups* (which you can download at www.math.wisc.edu/~ram/YaleNotes.pdf) he proves the case $q\neq 2$, $3$, $4$, or $9$ [pgs. 85ff in the PDF]. In chapter 7 of Karpilovsky's *The Schur Multiplier*, he proves the case $n>4$. So there are only a handful of possible exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that there can be small exceptions to the general rule: for example, $A_{6} \cong {\rm PSL}(2,9)$, and $A_{6}$ has a triple cover. Hence the Schur multiplier of $A_{6}$ has order $6$, and ${\rm SL}(2,9)$ has a triple cover.

Comment: SL(2,4) has SL(2,5) as a double cover too.  I think SL(2,F) otherwise has a trivial Schur multiplier, but three other SL(n,F) are exceptional too.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should probably have said I'm willing to rule out the cases $SL \left( 2,4 \right)$ and $SL \left(2,9\right)$.